# Only getting old events from FQL query of events of a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the events from my societies facebook page onto my societies webpage, and I'm using this query, which has worked before

```
SELECT eid, name, pic_square, start_time, location  
FROM event  WHERE creator = 195359493828725 
OR eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 195359493828725)
```

This is for this facebook page btw: https://www.facebook.com/eeunsw and here is the website that is scraping from it: http://www.elsoc.net/events.php

As you can see - it doesn't seem to be working too well - the most recent event was from last year, despite having far more recent events since then. It stopped working all of sudden recently and prototyping on the facebook graph api tool didn't reveal anything else.

Has something changed with FQL? This was working before and now it isn't. Looking over the forums, the above code should work.

Am I doing something wrong, or has there been a change to the access tokens. Since this is an open page, an access token should have enough privileges to view all the events. And why is it only selecting a subset of the older events?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a [known bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/426799594081557). Please file a repro.

Comment: @cpilko thanks for that - I was sure it was a bug at facebook's end, but I had no idea how to find out.